# Writing methods section on PCR amplication in a paper

Tags: microbiology

Considering that I am writing a paper for a journal, could the following phrase be understood? or should I put the 'step-by-step' way by giving numbers?

**PCR Amplification and sequencing**

PCR reaction for sequencing with universal primer  ITS5: F: (5’TCCTCCGCTTATTGATATGC3’ and ITS4:R: (5'TCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCG
C3'), including 5,8S rDNA region (White et al 1990). Amplification condition  was performed in a 25 ml reaction volume and consisting of 10 µL nuclease free water, 12.5 µL Tag green master mix, 0,5 µL forward primer, 0,5 µL reverse primer, 0,5 µLDMSO, 1 µL template. Mixture solution  was amplified by PCR machine (Biorad). Thermal cycle programmed for 90 seconds at 95°C as initial denaturation, followed by 35 cycles of 30 sec at 95°C for denaturation, 30 sec at 55 °C as annealing, 90 sec at 72 °C for extension, and final extension at 72 °C for 5 min. PCR products were examined by electrophoresis  at 100 V for 30 minutes in a 1% (w/v) agarose gel in 1 x TAE buffer. The marker used DNA ladder 1 kb.  Electrophoresis gel was soaked in ethidium bromide for 30 minutes then visualized in UV light.

Comment: You should change your "Amplification..." sentence to remove the word "condition" and change 25 ml to 25 µL, but other than that it looks okay. Also, maybe spell out "Forward" and "Reverse" when listing your primers.

Comment: Is Tag meant to be Taq?

Comment: @AlanBoyd Is there any reference as a guidance for writing a journal; cases like 'mins should be min' and 'secs should s', and other abbreviation in (micro)biology term.  Should I only learn from the previous reviews/journals? Thanks.

Comment: @Des-microbiology [this site](http://abacus.bates.edu/~ganderso/biology/resources/writing/HTWgeneral.html) looks like a reasonable place to start.

Comment: @des: according to the [SI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) (which is the reference for these matters) the abbreviation for seconds is `s` not `sec`.

Comment: @AlanBoyd what is the abbreviation of diameter? dia Or diam? The references in my hand do not provide it. The context is: Phomopsis sp (3).

Cultural characteristic: Colony of  2-3-1-B2 isolate on potato dextrose agar after 7 d, fast growing fungus, abundant with aeral mycelium, cotton-like, white colour, 51 mm diam, serrated edges colony.

Comment: @des There isn't a "correct" abbreviation for diameter - it isn't a physical unit in the same way that seconds or minutes are. However specific journals probably have their own rules - check their Style Guide.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take, just a few minor changes which are shown in **bold** (I have also changed `,`to `.` for decimal numbers and added a few spaces where needed):

> **PCR Amplification and sequencing**
>
> A PCR reaction for sequencing was performed using universal primers ITS5: F:
>   (5’TCCTCCGCTTATTGATATGC3’) and ITS4:R: (5'TCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCG C3'),
>   including **5.8 S rRNA** region (White ***et al.*** 1990). Amplification <del>**condition**</del>
>   was performed in a 25 ml reaction volume and consisting of 10 µL
>   nuclease free water, 12.5 µL Taq green master mix, 0.5 µL forward
>   primer, 0.5 µL reverse primer, 0.5 µL DMSO, 1µL template. **PCR was performed using a Biorad PCR machine**. The thermal cycle **was**
>   programmed for 90 **s** at 95 °C **for** initial denaturation, followed by
>   35 cycles of 30 s at 95 °C for denaturation, 30 s at 55 °C **for**
>   annealing, 90 s at **72 °C** for extension, and **5 min at 72 °C for the final extension.**
>   PCR products were examined by electrophoresis at 100 V for
>   30 min in a 1% (w/v) agarose gel in 1 x TAE buffer. The marker
>   used **a 1 kb DNA ladder**. **The** electrophoresis gel was soaked in ethidium
>   bromide for 30 min then **examined** in UV light.

Comment: The first sentence is not a sentence.

Comment: @terdon or even better, use the correct abbreviation for seconds which is s, not sec(s). And use min for minutes (never mins)

Comment: @AlanBoyd thanks! It's 22:00 here and I'm still in my lab writing a report for a grant I received, so my mind is not at its best. I _knew_ that sec bothered me but I couldn't put my finger on it. WHile absolutely correct, your comment about _min_ is nicely ironic given that what I read is: "@terdon or even better, use the correct abbreviation for seconds which is s, not sec(s). And use min for minutes (not mins) – Alan Boyd 4 **mins** ago". :)

Comment: @kmm indeed it was not.

Comment: Tag should probably be Taq...

Comment: @terdon I use rDNA not rRNA.